# Display all records of an id on separate rows for each id php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

i have this table resulted from some inner joins

```
id_outfit   | name | article
----------------------------------------
   56        | one  | shoe.png
   56        | one  | dress.png
   56        | one  | bag.png
   54        | two  | shoe1.png
   54        | two  | dress2.png
```

Column 'article' contains images.

I try to display in my app all the articles from an id_outfit on a single row, but I don't know how to do that.

For example I try to display all articles that have id 56 on a row ,all articles that have id 54 on the next row and so on .

I tried to do this with GROUP BY but for each id it  displays only the first image(article) .

Any suggestion is very helpful for me, thank you !

Comment: What do you mean by "display in my app"?

Comment: Please include the code you are using to display the table.

Comment: Please don't just repost the same question under a different userid.

Comment: Show your best attempt please. In theory if you order the query by ID, then it should be a simple case of looping the results, checking on each row whether the ID is the same as on the previous row (for that you need a variable to hold the previous row's ID) and if the IDs are different then start a new row (if not, then don't) - this logic is not complex.

Comment: @David  SELECT outfit_articles.id_outfit, outfits.name, outfit_articles.article FROM outfits INNER JOIN outfit_articles ON outfits.id_outfit = outfit_articles.id_outfit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way do it using the PDO syntax:

```
<?php
try{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb", $user, $pass);
}
catch (Exception $e){
    //Handle your connection errors
}

//Request the things you need
$req = $db->query("SELECT id_outfit, article FROM your_table ORDER BY id_outfit DESC");

$tempId = null;

//start to loop through your data
while ($data = $req->fetch()){

  //if the outfit id is different than the last time we went through the loop:
  if($data["id_outfit"] !== $tempId){
    //close the previous row unless this is the first time through the loop
    echo $tempId === null ? "" : "</div>";
    //start a new row
    echo "<div class='row'>";
  }

  //now we display the image
  echo "<img src='" . $data["article"] . "' alt='youralt' >";
  //store the id we had for the next loop to check
  $tempId = $data["id_outfit"];
}

//close the last row
echo "</div>";

?>
```

This will output a `div` of class "row" for each different ID in your DB, contain all the images corresponding to that ID.

Then you can style those div using css to display it as a row, most likely using a flexbox:

```
.row{
  display: flex;
}
```

(you will need more css than that to make it actually pretty obviously.)